# Why is email not returned with api connector when SSO with azure b2c?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an user flow with an API connector. I'm using the ["before sending the token"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow#before-sending-the-token-preview) api connector to retrieve the user's role in my database and then sending it back in the token as extension_Role.

Everything works fine when I'm doing the normal flow, which for me is:

- Sign-up
- Disconnect
- Sign-in

This works fine because in the sign-up I manually enter the email and in the sign-in I also manually enter the email. In both those cases, I have the email claim received by my C# backend api connector.

Where it gets tricky is when I'm going to another website, using the same user flow, but with SSO activated. This means that it won't trigger me to enter my credentials again, but it will try to log me in in the background. When it's doing that, I still have my C# backend called, but this time there is not email. This is the received JSON:

```json
{
    "step":"PreTokenIssuance",
    "client_id":"HIDDEN FOR SECURITY",
    "ui_locales":"en-US",
    "objectId":"HIDDEN FOR SECURITY",
    "surname":"HIDDEN FOR SECURITY",
    "displayName":"HIDDEN FOR SECURITY",
    "givenName":"HIDDEN FOR SECURITY"
}
```

I was wondering why I don't have the email.

There are the application claims and user claims on my user flow:
[image: App claims]
[image: User attribute]

If there is no real solution to this issue, one would be to create a new custom field named "AutomaticEmail" and to fill ou this field with the user email on sign-up. This will work, but I think that this is a dumb solution since there's already a field email for this purpose and if the user change email for whatever reason, there will be a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   It is because when you are logging into another website, it is an untrusted domain and even though the claims in the backend C# json file are hidden after authenticating through SSO, the claims output in the token received are encrypted while the email claim attribute is omitted while other claim attributes are still present in the token received even though being hidden/encrypted.

•   So, the email claim attribute might be returned null in the json file as its value in the column might be missing or unknown. So, when an element is null, either the key-value pair regarding the email attribute is omitted and returns a value that corresponds to the Azure AD B2C claim data type. Thus, since the email claim attribute is a string type, it returns empty string as “” just as the email attribute is unseen in the authentication token received.

•   Also, add the below claim to the custom policy output claims so that you will be able to get email as an attribute in response token as may be your custom policy might allow you to signup/sign in through multiple attribute claim types and you might not be getting email claim when using other claim types other than email.

```
    <!-- This was already here -->
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
   <!-- Added claim -->
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" 
    PartnerClaimType="email" />
```

Please find the link below which explains the API connectors to extend and customize the user-signup flows as well as the handling of null values returned: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/406952/email-claim-sometimes-missing-in-b2c-tokens.html